# Is it possible to make a transaction ignore

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So if I have something like

```
CREATE TABLE FakeTable (NotNullColumn INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn) VALUES (NULL);
```

then obviously I get an error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NotNullColumn', table
>   'Merchant_BizarroNordstrom.dbo.FakeTable'; column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails.

I'm wondering if there's a way to temporarily, i.e. within the context of a transaction, make it so that inserting `NULL` into a column with a `NOT NULL` constraint results in nothing happening rather than an error.

If you're curious what my real-life problem is, there's a giant query I don't want to spend hours reading and debugging and so I want to apply a quick fix.

Comment: can you use a temporary table instead of going directly to the physical table?

Comment: The `NOT NULL` constraint may be there for a reason, e.g. due to reference integrity.  Are you sure it is wise to hack around this?

Comment: This is the second poorly documented and explained question from a single user in a matter of hours. I would recommend reporting it as abuse and moving on to questions that don't insult the SO community.

Comment: @Anthony: Then I guess we need to report the majority of SO users for abuse :)

Comment: The short answer is: No you can't. Do it properly instead. You're asking if you can break integrity rules in a database and the answer is no, and for good reason. Do it properly - fix your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TRY..CATCH blocks

Something like....

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
      INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn) VALUES (NULL);
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  PRINT 'Do something or nothing here'

END CATCH
```

Using try..catch block gives you the control of when the error is raised if something goes wrong.

In the Try block because the null value cannot be Inserted, the control jumps to Catch block, there you can explicitly raise an error or do nothing.

**EDIT**

After reading your comment I think you need an Instead of Insert trigger. Something like ....

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_Into_FakeTable 
ON FakeTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn)
  SELECT NotNullColumn
  FROM inserted
  WHERE NotNullColumn IS NOT NULL

END
```

The Trigger will be fired instead of the actual Insert statement and only the non-null values will be inserted.

Comment: But I want to do nothing only for the null insertions. For example, If I had `INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn) VALUES (NULL, 5);` then I still want 5 inserted.

Answer (score -1):

> But I want to do nothing only for the null insertions. For example, If
>   I had INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn) VALUES (NULL, 5); then I
>   still want 5 inserted.

```
INSERT INTO FakeTable (NotNullColumn, othercolumn) VALUES (ISNULL(@VAL_THAT_MIGHT_BE_NULL,''), 5);
```

this will take care of your req. OFcourse it goes without saying that it is converting a NULL Value to a empty string and that your application needs to be able to handle this. If your application does not expect a empty string then this wont work.

Comment: guys Please feel free to explain the downvotes .... so that i can improve/remove the answer. Thx

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP's question.  In your defense, the comment from OP that you quoted is very misleading. What OP meant to say was: *If I had the following 2 insert statements: insert into fakeTable (null); insert into fakeTable (5);, instead of getting an error on the first insert, I just want it to be ignored so that the second statement succeeds.*  Hope that clears it up.  Then again, I could be wrong too :)

Comment: @sstan lol makes sense but I will wait for the OP to show up and explain ... thx

Comment: @Ms. Corlib please explain